# Trying to match a column's value with another container multiple values

Tags: google-bigquery

I have two tables, with the same column name/type.

```
Table A: Property listings
ID | Postal Code | Town
12 | xxxxx | California
13 | xxxxx | Nashville
14 | xxxxx | New York

Table B: User preferences
ID | Name | Preferred Towns
909| Dave | ["California", "New York"]
```

The town column in Table A is a string.
The preferred towns in Table B is a json array.

The goal is to match Dave with property listings located in specific town(s).

```
Expected output:
User to Property Matches
User ID | User Name | Matched Property ID
909 | Dave | 12, 14
```

Comment: what is your expected output bro? can please add the output

Comment: Done! Added the expected output

Comment: so mysql or bigquery?!

Answer (score 0):

Consider below approach (BigQuery)

```
select ID as User_ID, Name as User_Name, 
  ( select string_agg(p.ID)
    from t.Preferred_Towns Town
    join Property_listings p
    using (Town)
  ) Matched_Property_ID
from User_Preferences t
```

If applied to sample data in your question as in below example

```
with Property_listings as (
  select '12' ID, 'xxxxx' PostalCode, 'California' Town union all
  select '13', 'xxxxx', 'Nashville' union all
  select '14', 'xxxxx', 'New York' 
), User_Preferences as (
  select '909' ID, 'Dave' Name, ["California", "New York"] Preferred_Towns 
)
select ID as User_ID, Name as User_Name, 
  ( select string_agg(p.ID)
    from t.Preferred_Towns Town
    join Property_listings p
    using (Town)
  ) Matched_Property_ID
from User_Preferences t
```

the output is

[image]